# Android dynamic Fragment recreated several times on Screen orientation change, after onclick list selection

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, android-listfragment

I am working on the following [tutorial](https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples/FragmentDynamicLayoutWithActionBar), it has problems : it recreates the fragments after each screen rotation.
I fixed it concerning the **TitlesFragment** class by adding **if(savedInstanceState == null)** in **QuoteViewerActivity**:

```
mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
//ADDED THIS CONDITION
if(savedInstanceState == null){
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.title_fragment_container, mTitlesFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

it fixed it for Fragment **TitlesFragment** however for Fragment **QuoteFragment** it is still recreating it on each screen orientation change because in this tutorial that fragment is created in an onclick event:

```
@Override
public void onListSelection(int index) {
  if (!mDetailsFragment.isAdded()) {
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.quote_fragment_container, mDetailsFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
   mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
  }
  if (mDetailsFragment.getShownIndex() != index) {
     mDetailsFragment.showIndex(index);
  }
}
```

**note that setRetainInstance(true) is set in both fragment's onCreate()**.

I tried to add this checking but it didn't fix it:

```
@Override
public void onListSelection(int index) {

  //ADDED THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES
     Fragment f = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.quote_fragment_container);
     if(f == null)
  //===============================

  if (!mDetailsFragment.isAdded()) {
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.quote_fragment_container, mDetailsFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
   mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
  }
  if (mDetailsFragment.getShownIndex() != index) {
     mDetailsFragment.showIndex(index);
  }
}
```

**==> It recreates this Fragment each time I rotate the screen and duplicates existing menus (explained in this snapshot):**

[image: output_snapshot]

### What am I doing wrong and what is the best practice to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

In **this** specific tutorial the solution for this problem was solved by:

- using **onSaveInstanceState** to store **QuoteFragment** state to its containing activity
- Getting/handling the **QuoteFragment** by checking if it is found in the **savedInstanceState**

Here is what I added/changed in the code:

```
.....
private  QuoteFragment mDetailsFragment = new QuoteFragment();//REMOVED final attribute
......

//ADDED
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(quote_fragment_tag)!=null)
        getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, QuoteFragment.class.getName(), mDetailsFragment);
}

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TitleArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Titles);
    QuoteArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Quotes);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    // ADDED
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.title_fragment_container, mTitlesFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
    else{//ADDED
        mDetailsFragment = (QuoteFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .getFragment(savedInstanceState, QuoteFragment.class.getName());
       if(mDetailsFragment == null){
            mDetailsFragment = new QuoteFragment();
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.quote_fragment_container, mDetailsFragment,quote_fragment_tag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();  
            mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
       }
       }
}
```

## Note:

**in my humble opinion** for best practices concerning fragments and config changes on runtime check [Google's official tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 1):

This line won't find the fragment you're trying to find:

```
Fragment f = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.quote_fragment_container);
```

You provided container (layout) id. This method can be used to find fragments that were inflated from XML layout.

If you want to manage fragments from code, use `tag`. Add a fragment using `FragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`. Providing a `tag` you can later find that fragment using `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag)`. It's a good idea to make `tag` some kind of `static final String` constant, making automatic refactoring a breeze.

You may be also interested with method `FragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)` - it makes fragment replacement easier.

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips, however finding by tag solely didn't solve it, check my solution for details.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution.Add

> menu.clear()

before inflating the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu method inside the fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


    }
```